# GSON returns StackOverflowError: null

Tags: java, gson

I'm trying to transform my HashMap into a JSON string using Google's lib. GSON.

I've tried using Jackson's ObjectMapper but it didn't work either. I've tried to put some transient and some things I found on other topics without success.

It is currently returning an error (without any line specified):

```java
//ERROR 
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl.getGenericDeclaration(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.declaringClassOf($Gson$Types.java:427) ~[$Gson$Types.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolveTypeVariable($Gson$Types.java:397) ~[$Gson$Types.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:329) ~[$Gson$Types.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:158) ~[ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100) ~[ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423) ~[Gson.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115) ~[ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.class:?]

// HashMap I need in JSON
public class Storage {

    static @Getter @Setter HashMap<World, HashMap<Chunk, List<Particle>>> storage = new HashMap<>();

}
// Class to load/save the data file
public class StorageManager {

    public static File folder, config;
    private static final Gson GSON = new Gson();

    public static void setup(File _folder){
        folder = _folder;
    }

    public static void load() throws IOException {
        if(!folder.exists())
            folder.mkdir();
        config = new File(folder, "particles.json");
        if(!config.exists()) {
            config.createNewFile();
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(config, false);
            writer.write(GSON.toJson(Storage.getStorage()));
            writer.close();
        }
        FileReader content = new FileReader(config);
        Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<World, HashMap<Chunk, List<Particle>>>>(){}.getType();
        Storage.setStorage(GSON.fromJson(content, type));
    }

    public static void save() throws IOException {
        String json = GSON.toJson(Storage.getStorage());
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(config, false);
        writer.write(json);
        writer.close();
    }

}
```

I need to be able to load the file, get the JSON and replace my currently empty Hashmap with the data from the file. I also need to save the file with the new Hashmap data.

Comment: 1) the stacktrace is terse. Please post more of it to make in evidence the location of the overflow error 2) Which statement causes the issue ?

Comment: Added the full error (Some part is spammed so I put it once). There's no line specified

Comment: @CharlesAdorty Can you post a reproducible example (such as a unit test), on https://ideone.com/ for instance? The stack overflow might be caused by the way the other classes are annotated: World,  Chunk, Particle, etc. A unit test would help you (and us) quickly try things. More about this: http://sscce.org/

Comment: It's a plugin (no main), so there's no way to try without the actual game server.